# 'mkfilter' command in MATLAB to design bessel type filters

Tags: matlab, filter

I have implemented a simple script which compares Butterworth, Chebyshev and Bessel filters for a range of filter orders.  The code, when run, produces the expected results, with the exception of the bessel filter implementations.  I am getting an error:

```
Error in FilterComparison (line 75)
bes_1 = mkfilter(fc, 1, 'bessel');
```

I have tried multiple things but can't seem to remove this error.  I have included the full code below:

```
%Script to compare the responses of various analogue filters
%including bessel, chebyshev and butterworth.
%mkfilter command syntax
%example = mkfilter (cutoff freq, order, 'type');

clear all
close all

%Cut off frequency
fc = 2000;

%Determines whether figures are displayed or not.
%Silent = 1, no display
silent = 1;

%BUTTERWORTH FILTERS
%1st order butterworth filter
butter_1 = mkfilter(fc, 1, 'butterw');

%2nd order butterworth filter
butter_2 = mkfilter(fc, 2, 'butterw');

%3rd order butterworth filter
butter_3 = mkfilter(fc, 3, 'butterw');

%4th order butterworth filter
butter_4 = mkfilter(fc, 4, 'butterw');

%5th order butterworth filter
butter_5 = mkfilter(fc, 5, 'butterw');

%6th order butterworth filter
butter_6 = mkfilter(fc, 6, 'butterw');

%Bode plot
if ~silent
    figure(1)
    bode(butter_1, 'red',butter_2, 'blue',butter_3, 'green',butter_4, 'cyan',butter_5,     'black',butter_6, 'magenta')
    legend('n = 1','n = 2','n = 3','n = 4', 'n = 5', 'n = 6')
end

%CHEBYSHEV FILTERS
%1st order chebyshev filter
cheby_1 = mkfilter(fc, 1, 'Cheby', 2);

%2nd order chebyshev filter
cheby_2 = mkfilter(fc, 2, 'Cheby', 2);

%3rd order chebyshev filter
cheby_3 = mkfilter(fc, 3, 'Cheby', 2);

%4th order chebyshev filter
cheby_4 = mkfilter(fc, 4, 'Cheby', 2);

%5th order chebyshev filter
cheby_5 = mkfilter(fc, 5, 'Cheby', 2);

%6th order chebyshev filter
cheby_6 = mkfilter(fc, 6, 'Cheby', 2);

%Bode plot
if ~silent
    figure(2) %open figure 2
    bode(cheby_1, 'red',cheby_2, 'blue',cheby_3, 'green',cheby_4, 'cyan',cheby_5, 'black',cheby_6, 'magenta')
    legend('n = 1','n = 2','n = 3','n = 4', 'n = 5', 'n = 6')
end

%BESSEL FILTERS
%1st order bessel filter
bes_1 = mkfilter(fc, 1, 'bessel');

%2nd order bessel filter
bes_2 = mkfilter(fc, 2, 'bessel');

%3rd order bessel filter
bes_3 = mkfilter(fc, 3, 'bessel');

%4th order bessel filter
bes_4 = mkfilter(fc, 4, 'bessel');

%5th order bessel filter
bes_5 = mkfilter(fc, 5, 'bessel');

%6th order bessel filter
bes_6 = mkfilter(fc, 6, 'bessel');

%Bode Plot
figure(3)
bode(bes_1, 'red',bes_2, 'blue',bes_3, 'green',bes_4, 'cyan',bes_5, 'black',bes_6,         'magenta')
legend('n = 1','n = 2','n = 3','n = 4', 'n = 5', 'n = 6')

%Plot 3rd order filters for comparison
figure (4)
bode(cheby_3, 'red', bes_3, 'blue', butter_3, 'green')
legend('Chebyshev', 'Bessel', 'Butterworth')
```

Thanks in advance.
P.s, I am new to stack overflow, so apologies for formatting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a bug in `mkfilter` for the bessel filters which causes the 1st and 2nd order bessel filters to return this error.
You can fix it by editing `mkfilter` (use `edit mkfilter` to open the file):

Starting at line 58:

```
if ord == 1,
    sys = nd2sys(1,b1);
elseif ord == 2,
    sys = nd2sys(1,b2);
...
```

Change this into:

```
if ord == 1,
    sys = tf(1,b1);
elseif ord == 2,
    sys = tf(1,b2);
...
```

Comment: Thanks for the response 0xMB.  How do I edit in-built functions?  When I input 'edit mkfilter' at the command window it opens a read only version.  Is there a way that I can make it writeable?

Comment: One way to solve this is to copy the contents of the `mkfilter` function into a new function file and place this in your current working directory. You can then apply the modification. MATLAB will then use this modified function instead of the built-in function. You can also use `which mkfilter` and change the permissions on that file.